# how can i place a CtabFolder inside another CTabfolder in SWT

Tags: java, swt

Please help me, I am abeginner to SWT.
I want to place a `CTabFolder` inside another `CTabFolder`.
I have tried the following code, but its incomplete.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashForm;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import sun.awt.HorizBagLayout;

    public class LayoutExample2
    {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display display=new Display();
        Shell shell=new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());  

        CTabFolder ctf_main=new CTabFolder(shell,SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        CTabItem ctb1=new CTabItem(ctf_main,SWT.NONE);
        ctf_main.setSimple(false);
        ctf_main.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        ctf_main.pack();
        ctb1.setText("Error Management Portal      ");

         CTabFolder ctf_inner=new CTabFolder(ctf_main,SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
         CTabItem tbi1=new CTabItem(ctf_main,SWT.FLAT);
         tbi1.setText("Search ");


            shell.setMaximized(true);
            shell.pack();
            shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
    }
```

please help me to put a `Ctabfolder` inside another `Ctabfolder`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see these problems:

Your inner `CTabItem` `tbi1` has the wrong parent, it should have the inner folder as its parent:

```
CTabItem tbi1 = new CTabItem(ctf_inner, SWT.FLAT);
```

You need to tell `CTabItem` about the control which it manages with the `CTabItem.setControl()` method. So the outer tab has the inner folder as its control:

```
ctb1.setControl(ctf_inner);
```

You probably also need to create a child of the inner folder to get things to display properly:

```
Composite innerComp = new Composite(ctf_inner, SWT.NONE);

tbi1.setControl(innerComp);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `CTabItem` has no `setContent()`method.